Repository version storage issues
I have a problem with my code, I need to extract the release version of my program in order to compare versions and, if necessary, update it.
My full program is in this repository:autonetplan
The specific file I need help is this one: autonetplan.sh Line 296-320
I'm having problems  on the update system, the input is: autonetplan -u
And the output is: jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 8, colum 10
# Revisar actualización y comparar
        # Obtener la última versión desde GitHub sobre el programa
        latest_release=$(curl -s "https://github.com/Nisamov/autonetplan/releases/tag/autonetplan" | jq -r '.tag_name')
        # Obtener ultima version
        # Extraer el número de versión del nombre del release
        latest_version=$(echo "$latest_release" | sed -n 's/.*v\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
        # Verificar si hay una nueva versión disponible
        if [[ "$latest_version" != "$current_version" ]]; then
            echo "¡Nueva versión disponible! Versión actual: $current_version, Última versión: $latest_version"
            # Solicitar actualizacion
            read -p "¿Desea actualizar el programa? [s/n]: " updaterequest
            if [[ $updaterequest == "s" ]]; then
                # Código para actualizar el programa
                echo "Actualizando el programa..."
            elif [[ $updaterequest == "n" ]]; then
                # Cancelacion de actualizacion
                echo "[#] Se ha cancelado la actualizacion"
                exit 1
            else
                echo "[#] Se ha añadido un parámetro no registrado, cancelando actualización..."
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Tu programa ya está actualizado. Versión actual: $current_version"
        fi


Regarding the error: In curl -s "https://github.com/Nisamov/autonetplan/releases/tag/autonetplan" | jq -r '.tag_name', curl fetches a file from the given url, while jq interprets it as JSON as extracts some data. But jq fails because the file fetched is not JSON. The url just points to a guthub page (so jq gets HTML content instead of JSON -- try opening that page in your browser, view the page source, and see that after 7 blank lines the 8th begins with <!DOCTYPE html> , thus the error on line 8).

I you want json output you probably want to query github's API

You may want to have a look at GitHub's documentation on how to use REST API endpoints for releases

Use GitHub API to get the release:
latest_release=$(
  curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Nisamov/autonetplan/releases | jq .[0].name
)

